# Execution time of GetDC on Windows 8

Tags: delphi, winapi

Im trying to check if there pixel with white (#FFFFFF) or green (#00FF00) color of the screen's region. Usualy its 500x500 (250'000 pixels). Im checking every 5th pixel:

```
x := iMRXDef; // starting region coordinates
y := iMRYDef;
while DoMR do // global boolean variable
  begin
    inc(x, 4);
    if x >= iMRXMax then  // ending region coordinates
      if y < iMRYMax then
        begin
          inc(y, 4);
          x := iMRXDef;
        end
      else
        begin
          x := iMRXDef;
          y := iMRYDef;
        end;
    DC := GetDC(0);
    ColorValue := GetPixel(DC, X, Y);
    ReleaseDC(0, DC);
    if (ColorValue = iMRColorV) or (ColorValue = iMRColorV2) then
      begin
        performClick(X, Y); // clicking by SendInput.
        x := x + 30; // skip some area
        y := y + 20;
        sleep(500);
      end;
  end;
```

For some reason, on win8 running my programm takes a lot of time (couple of minutes) whilst on win7 its about couple of seconds. What causes this difference?

Comment: Is there a reason for Get/ReleaseDC *inside* the loop? `GetDIBits` can be used to load the pixels into an array in a single pass.

Comment: Is your Win8 PC the same as the Win7 PC?

Comment: Blit the entire screen onto a temporary bitmap, lock the pixels, and look at them with direct memory access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a screenshot of the area you're interested in and read the pixels from that bitmap. Then access the pixels from the scanlines property of the bitmap if possible. Should be a lot faster.

GetPixel is generally not a fast function. And some Windows 8 screen dpi changes can also slow down graphics quite a lot. So it is hard to tell what is slowing down your code. You'd have to profile your code if you want to know which part is so much slower on this Win8 PC.

Comment: I've debug it and it seems like [GetDC, getPixel, ReleaseDC] part slows on Win8 for 5 times... PCs is just a bit different (both intel quad core, 4gb RAM, etc.).

Comment: GetPixel has always been slow, especially compared to a direct memory read using the ScanLine property. I don't know how W8 GetPixel() compares to other OSes, in this respect, but ScanLine is generally MUCH faster, and independent of the OS. Therefore: +1.